# How to launch the download of a file without leaving the current page?

Tags: asp.net, download, viewstate

How can I force the download of a file on a ASP.NET page using datas from that page's ViewState? I found examples suggesting:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "example.aaa");
Response.Write( this.ViewState["stuffs"] );
Response.End();
```

But if I do that the current page will be erased and return blank to the user.

Other examples says to create "download.aspx" and request it by javascript, but on a this new page I won't have access to the ViewState data of the first page.

The point is, how can I create a file, launch the download and don't lose the current page status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more test I found a solution.

If I remove the `Response.ClearContent();` from the example code, it will work exactly as I need:

- creating the new file using the actual page data
- launching the download of this file
- preserving the actual page intact

Answer (score -1):

I usually handle this by using Crystal Reports and generating a PDF file.  I save a reference to that file with the submitted data and serve it up when requested.  You'll want to protect the file so a random URL hacker can't stumble upon it.

Comment: The security problem about the URL is not a concerning because this form is only accessed by logged users. I don't know if the CrystalReports fit on my scenario because until the click on finish button nothing is saved on the database.

Comment: Sure, but could one logged user play around with the URL/Querystring and display the results from another logged user?

Comment: I don't think so.. the data comes from the ViewState. It is unique for each user and each page.

Comment: Yes, but I'm suggesting you generate the PDF document at the time the application is submitted.  This will make sure you have a "snapshot in time" version of your application.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is exactly that... how can I create the file (pdf, .txt, whatever) and don't lose the current page?

Comment: The data is being saved to the database, correct?  After it is saved, create the report from the data you saved.